# Email confirmation rubyonrails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, confirmation

I'm trying to create a website where the user signs up with his user name, password and email address. Then he should be sent a confirmation email which generates a link he will have to click on to make his account approved.

How would I do that, anyone who has a tutorial that's very simple and easy?
I'm just looking for the most simple and easiest email confirmation code.

Thanks,
Michael.

Comment: This question is very open-ended, and the problem with this is that the "best" answers are usually along the lines of the one already here, links to external tutorials. In other words, SO does not really work well when the best answers are complete tutorials. I'm going to close this as not-constructive, since it is not a good fit, and you should look at the tutorials linked in the answer below, and if you have a more concrete question later on, that would be a much more fitting question for SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These may be informative for you:

http://asciicasts.com/episodes/274-remember-me-reset-password

http://asciicasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch

Also you may use a devise as a working solution:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise or just learn from reading the code and how it's been implemented :)